# Видимость приватных полей

Tags: java

Не могу понять почему компилятор не ругается на `someclass.field`:

```
public class Someclass {

    private int field;

    public int method(Someclass someclass) {
        return this.field - someclass.field;
    }
}
```

Поле `field` же `private` и, как я понимаю, при обращении через переменную `someclass` должно быть недоступно.

Comment: да, но только `не` внутри класса, в котором объявлено, это таки его область видимости

Answer (score 2):

Компилятор Вас не обманывает.

Предполагается что `private` поле будет использоваться только `внутри класса`, в котором оно объявлено.

Ваш пример никак не нарушает это правило, вы обращаетесь хоть и к полю объекта переданного по ссылке, но все-таки это `экземпляр этого же класса`, в котором и происходит обращение к полю. Так что все легально.

Answer (score 1):

Ключевое слово - `Private` - оно ограничивает видимость данных и методов пределами одного класса, т.к. у Вас все в пределах одного класса, ругаться и не будет, но если Вы попробуете вызвать переменную таким образов в другом классе, данный метод не сработает